# PHP For loop required for storing data in MySQL

Tags: php, variables, loops

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($proc, "iss$is", $respondent_id, $ip, $browser, $qStr1);
```

It's just this that is causing the problem, even though `$qStr1` contains the text $q1, $q2 etc. as things stand I think `$qStr1` is being treated as a single variable within the code, I guess I need to extract the text and then use it but no sure how?

**Using the answer provided below, I have modified and added to:**

```
$qStr = '';
    $markStr = '';
    for($i=1; $i<11; $i++)
    {
        $qStr .= 'q'.$i.'';
        $qStr1 .= '$q'.$i.'';
        $markStr .= '?';
        $is .= 'i';
        if($i < 10)
        {
            $qStr .= ', ';
            $qStr1 .= ', ';
            $markStr .= ', ';
        }
    }

$proc = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO tresults (respondent_id, ip, browser, $qStr) VALUES (?, ?, ?, $markStr);");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($proc, "iss$is", $respondent_id, $ip, $browser, $qStr1);
```

Now, I'm having a problem with `$qStr1` - even though this is looping through and providing the correct output $q1, $q2 etc. - it's not saving to the DB, if I manually place $q1, $q2, etc in the `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` and leave the rest using the `loop` it works correctly.

I have the following code:

```
$proc = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO tresults (respondent_id, ip, browser, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($proc, "issiiiiiiiiii", $respondent_id, $ip, $browser, $q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $q5, $q6, $q7, $q8, $q9, $q10);

mysqli_stmt_execute($proc);
```

What I am trying to achieve is a `loop` (at least I think it is) that will place the `q1, q2, q3, q4, q5 etc.` automatically into that code and also place the correct numbers of `?` in there are well.

Is the question clear and can anyone assist?

Comment: What are you starting with – like an array of column names, or just a number of columns and all of the column names are build as `q`+number, or …? And what have your tried so far?

Comment: Hi @CBroe - hopefully the updates above are enough - just looking to resolve one final issue and then this will be perfect.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
    $qStr = '';
    $markStr = '';

    for($i=1; $i<11; $i++)
    {
        $qStr .= 'q'.$i.'';
        $markStr .= '?';
        if($i < 10)
        {
            $qStr .= ', ';
            $markStr .= ', ';
        }
    }


    $proc = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO tresults (respondent_id, ip, browser, $qStr) VALUES (?, ?, ?, $markStr);");
?>
```

The output of `$qStr` & `$markStr` will be like this

```
$qStr = q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,q7,q8,q9,q10
$markStr = ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?
```

Comment: Does it not put a ',' at the end of the last variable?

Comment: No, Should it put a comma at the end of last variable? I don't think so

Comment: No - it shouldn't so that should be correct.  Just testing now.

Comment: Please see the updated answer, The values should be like this `VALUES (?, ?, ?, $markStr)` the 3 `?` are for `respondent_id, ip, browser`

Comment: Hi Khawer, OK this works until I try to apply to the `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` section - I've updated the question above.  Thanks for your help, any further assistance welcomed.

Comment: Thanks Khawer - really appreciate you taking the time to respond but sadly, still not saving.

Comment: Make sure you have values set for all these variables like `$q1=11, $q2=22` etc.. and also if you can show me the error that will be helpful

Comment: Values are definitely set because if I use `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($proc, "iss$is", $respondent_id, $ip, $browser, $q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $q5, $q6, $q7, $q8, $q9, $q10);` it saves to the DB - when using your code above - there is no error message shown and nothing is saved to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

**edited!**

```
$proc = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO results 
          (respondent_id, ip, browser, $qStr) VALUES (?, ?, ?, 
            ?,?,?,?,?,
            ?,?,?,?,?);"
            );
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($proc, "iss$is", $respondent_id, $ip, $browser, 
            $q1,$q2,$q3,$q4,$q5,
            $q6,$q7,$q8,$q9,$q10
            );
mysqli_stmt_execute($proc);
```

Isn't that easier to read...?

Comment: See, the update above - that's what I am trying to implement based on Kkawers code but it's not saving to the DB.

Comment: Thanks @MBaas - I've just tried implementing and again, not saving to the DB.

Comment: Works with `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($proc, "iss$is", $respondent_id, $ip, $browser, $q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $q5, $q6, $q7, $q8, $q9, $q10);` but not with `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($proc, "iss$is", $respondent_id, $ip, $browser, $qStr1);`

Comment: I think it is because the `bind-param` $qStr1 is being treated as a single variable and not as the $q1, $q2 etc. that it actually contains - I guess I need to print it or echo it but not sure how to achieve this within PHP itself to make it a series of PHP variables that the `bin-param` can use.

Comment: Sorry, I see that I misunderstood your code :(  Do I understand right that you always have q1..q10 and you are trying to simplify the whole thing by building the bind-params programactically?

Comment: Yes, that is correct - it all works except for the `ysqli_stmt_bind_param($proc, "iss$is", $respondent_id, $ip, $browser, $qStr1);` as already detailed.

Comment: Ok, sorry, my fault then. I don't think this will actually work. IIRC bind_params needs variables there (because it will "store" the reference to that memory), so you can't put expressions there...
You could build the whole bind_param-statement as string in your q-loop and then use eval ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php ), but I would not do so. You'd be sacrificing a lot of readability for ...what?

Comment: The reason being is that have upwards of 10 pages with anywhere between 10 and 50 posts on each - therefore, by building programatically I don't have to manually change each page.

Comment: Any chance to change your DB-Driver to PDO? You could then use bindParam from PDO which has the nice possibility to numerically identify a parameter ( http://de1.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php )

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34156/discussion-between-homer-j-and-mbaas)

Comment: Sry, have to catch a train in a few minutes, will not have any more time today :(  Pls. have a look at the PDO-stuff, I think this is the nicest solution :)

Comment: Hi - what's the status? Got it working? Have you had a look at PDO? (Don't fear, it's easy to transfer from sqli to pdo!)